# Asp.Net Web API 2 error with local reference to JSON.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have cloned the repo for Json.Net on GitHub [https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json] and built a local copy of the dll.  I have been using this dll for a while now in a couple projects (console app and WebForms 4.0 site).  But now I have started a new Web API 2.2 project which automatically brings in references to Json.Net for use in `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` and `WebGrease` which both get installed by default in a new Web Api project.

I'm hoping to be able to take advantage of the optimizations provided by those dlls, but I need to reference my local version of the `Newtonsoft.Json` dll.  NuGet wont let me remove the Json.Net package b/c of the dependency from WebGrease, and if I manually remove the reference from the project and add a  reference to my local version of Json.Net, I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I am not sure how to get the references to line up so that I can use my local copy of the dll instead of the NuGet version that is expected by WebGrease.

This is in my .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\External\GitHub\Json.NET\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\bin\Debug\Net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

That local reference has `Copy Local = True` in the reference properties.

And this is in my web.config:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.3.0" newVersion="6.0.3.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

**How do I get this reference resolved?**

Comment: "but I need to reference my local version of the Newtonsoft.Json dll" Why? (Without this information all useful answers will boil down to using the normal, public, build of JSON.NET.)

Comment: B/c I have added in some custom parsing and limited schema validation that I needed for my JSON objects